# How to add a column to an SQL table that is a multiplication of two other columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called SalesOrderDetail and I need to append a column called "Revenue" which is the multiplication of two other columns: UnitPrice and OrderQty.

I am using the following code:

```
# creating columns revenue
ALTER TABLE SalesOrderDetail
ADD revenue DOUBLE NOT NULL;

# insert the revenues into the revenue column
INSERT INTO SalesOrderDetail(revenue)
SELECT UnitPrice*OrderQty
FROM SalesOrderDetail;
```

but I am getting the error: Error Code: 1048. Column 'revenue' cannot be null

Why is column revenue turning out to be null? I tried multiplicating both columns before and got the expected results, so it must be something in the code. Thank you!

Comment: If you are apending a column to existing rows, then you should be using an UPDATE and not an INSERT

Comment: 'Error Code: 1048. Column 'revenue' cannot be null' then either unitprice or orderquantity is null somewhere..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the column as a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE SalesOrderDetail
    ADD revenue NUMERIC(20, 4) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (UnitPrice*OrderQty) VIRTUAL;
```

It is then calculated when the value is used in a query.

Note that this uses a `NUMERIC` type instead of a floating point number.  Always use `NUMERIC`/`DECIMAL` for monetary amounts.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid data inconsistency, use a *generated column*:

```
ALTER TABLE SalesOrderDetail
ADD revenue NUMERIC(20, 4) 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (UnitPrice*OrderQty) STORED;
```

Comment: I think not null has to appear after stored. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hqq9QASHqk4tHCmUwubJPr/0

Comment: IMHO, as earlier answer says, don't use `DOUBLE` for monetary amounts, or you **WILL** get rounding issues

Comment: @P.Salmon, I'll make it nullable. (Perhaps it depends on the UnitPrice and OrderQty nullability.)

Comment: @James, I'll edit. (Wasn't my choice, I did just copy-and-paste...)